# Post Image from Blackberry WebWorks SDK Camera to PHP File Server

Tags: image, blackberry, upload, camera

I am using Blackberry webworks i want to upload image from camera to php webserver i am getting image in uri and it is displaying correctly but i dont know how to upload image to server please help.

file uri
file://dir/image name

i am using this code from blackberry webworks camera api

```
function takePicture() {
                            try {
                                blackberry.media.camera.takePicture(photoTaken, closedCB, errorCB);
                            } catch (e) {
                                //alert("Error in supported: " + e);
                            }
                        }

                        function successCB(filePath) {

                            var file = "file://" + filePath;
                            $("#myfileCam").val(file);
                            $("#imgPic").show();
                            $("#imgPic").attr("src", file);

                        }

                        function photoTaken(filePath) {

                            var img = new Image();
                            img.src = "file://" + filePath;
                            img.width = Math.round(screen.width / 2);
                            document.getElementById("path").appendChild(img);
                            var html = "<input type='file' name='myfile' id='myfile' value='file://" + filepath + "' />";
                            document.getElementById("fileup").innerHTML = html;
                            //$("#fileup").html();  
                            $("#myfileCam").val("file://" + filePath);

                        }

                        function closedCB() {
                            // alert("Camera closed event");
                        }

                        function errorCB(e) {
                            alert("Error occured: " + e);
                        }
```

Comment: get the image data from the image and send the data to the server.

Comment: do you have any particular example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
FileConnection fc= (FileConnection)Connector.open(filePath);
InputStream is=fc.openInputStream();
                    byte[] ReimgData = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
                    EncodedImage encode_image =EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(ReimgData, 0, (int)fc.fileSize());
                    JPEGEncodedImage encoder=JPEGEncodedImage.encode(encode_image.getBitmap(),50);
                    byte[] array=encoder.getData();
                    // Decodes the image represented by this EncodedImage and returns a Bitmap
                    int length=array.length;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(length);
                    Base64OutputStream base64OutputStream = new Base64OutputStream( byteArrayOutputStream );
                     try{
                                     base64OutputStream.write( array, 0, length );
                                     base64OutputStream.flush();
                                     base64OutputStream.close();
                                 }
                                    catch (IOException ioe){
                                    //Dialog.alert("Error in encodeBase64() : "+ioe.toString());
                                    System.out.println("Error in encodeBase64() : "+ioe.toString());

                                 }


 data = Base64InputStream.decode(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry i am using blackberry webworks and using javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

Use Phonegap for Blackberry Webworks I had the same problem and i resolved using this api.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer here everything you need.

The only thing you need to do is to put the phonegap jar file in ext folder and call for permissions en config.xml adding this feature (phonegap), and that it.

I hope this work to you, it worked to me.